# htaccess Rewrite rules for directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to have a rewrite rule that does the following:

User hits:

```
www.mysite.com/browse/red/cat/hat/joe.html/_/z-5
www.mysite.com/browse/shoes.html/_/z-2
www.mysite.com/browse/black/car.html/_/z-39a
```

Server reads to:

```
www.mysite.com/browse/red/cat/hat/joe.html?e=z-5
www.mysite.com/browse/shoes.html?e=z-2
www.mysite.com/browse/black/car.html?e=z-39a
```

So the key thing to go off of is the starting of browse and the "/_/".  I'm struggling with grabbing everything between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)/_/([^/]+)/?$ $1?e=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule (.*)\/_\/(.*) $1?e=$2 [L]`